# Can IIS prevent network user to get retrieved via vb code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication, iis

I'm having this situation: I've developed my first web ASP.NET app but I'm not the one who is uploading it to IIS; in fact I don't know anything about IIS and its configuration.
My web app  is supposed to work this way:
All of the computers in the company are inside a domain, and id users are retrieved using `Environment.UserName` then it's checked in users table and if that user has ADMIN rol `Default.aspx` will redirect to Administration page, otherwise it will redirect to Guest page.

It works well when I debug using Visual Studio, but when it is copied to the IIS site folder ( Is it "publishing"?) it always shows the Guest page.
For some reason `objArea.searchRol(id)` is not finding "ADM"
Is it possible that IIS configuration is blocking windows authentication or something like that?

My default.aspx page_load code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim objArea As New DataAccess.AreaDAO
        Dim id As String = Environment.UserName
        Dim rol As String = objArea.BuscarRol(id)
        If rol = "ADM" Then
        Response.Redirect("AdminPage.aspx")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("GuestPage.aspx")
    End If

    End Sub
```

And every other page has this code to validate user authentication:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim objArea As New DataAccess.AreaDAO
        Dim id As String = Environment.UserName
        Dim rol As String = objArea.searchRol(id)
        If rol <> "ADM" Then
            Response.Redirect("GuestPage.aspx")
        End If       

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable anonymous access, and enable Windows Authentication on IIS, and then, in `web.config`, set:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <identity impersonate ="true"/>
  <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
```

This will make the user be authenticated as the windows user when accessing the page through IIS.

Comment: Thanks, thought It still keeps loading guest page.